# How can you update a GUI with information from a function or adjacent file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to create a sensor panel that updates every second or two that draws information from Open Hardware Monitor. I have created a function that outputs a list of values pertaining to the desired information, however I cannot get it to update the GUI. This is a reduced version that only displays the CPU package temperature. It will display the initial value when run, but will not update. I plan to create an executable file out of this code that can be run on a tertiary screen to give constant stats on my computer.

```
import tkinter as tk
import wmi as w

root = tk.Tk()
i=0
def initialize():

    def update():
        w1 = w.WMI(namespace="root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
        temperature_infos = w1.Sensor()
        names = ['CPU Package' , 'GPU Core', 'CPU Total']
        values = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0]
        for sensor in temperature_infos:
            if sensor.SensorType == u'Temperature':
                if sensor.Name == names[0]:
                    values[0] = sensor.Value
                elif sensor.Name == names[1]:
                    values[1] = sensor.Value
                else:
                    pass
            elif sensor.SensorType == u'Load':
                if sensor.Name == names[2]:
                    values[2] = sensor.Value
                elif sensor.Name == names[1]:
                    values[3] = sensor.Value
                elif sensor.Name == u'GPU Memory':
                    values[4] = sensor.Value
                elif sensor.Name == u'Memory':
                    values[5] = sensor.Value
                else:
                    pass
            elif sensor.SensorType == u'Clock':
                if sensor.Name == u'CPU Core #8':
                    values[6] = sensor.Value
                else:
                    pass
            elif sensor.SensorType == u'Fan':
                if sensor.Name == u'Fan #5':
                    values[7] = sensor.Value
                elif sensor.Name == u'GPU Fan':
                    values[8] = sensor.Value
                else:
                    pass
        return values
    values = update()
    text = tk.StringVar()
    text.set(values[0])
    label1 = tk.Label(root, textvariable = text)
    global i
    if i == 0:
         label1.pack()
         i+=1
    else:
        label1.config(textvariable = text)
   
    root.after(1000,initialize)


root.after(1000,initialize)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: A common way to do this sort thing in a `tkinter` application is by using the universal widget [`after()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/universal.html) method to schedule a call to a specified function after a specified delay. If the called function _itself_ makes a call to `after()` then they can be made to happen repeatedly. The called function can change the appearance of the GUI if it wishes, depending on what it's doing. There are numerous answers here that show how to do this if you look for them…

Comment: @martineau I've reviewed extensively about the `after()` function in this case, however I wish to change the label using the `.config` function. The issue in this case is updating the label1 variable in a separate function that runs `label1.config` rather than `.pack()`. I am rather new to python so I apologize if I am missing something important.

Comment: I can't run your code because it's not a minimal [mre] and I don't have the `wmi` module installed. However here are my thoughts: Since you're using a  `Label` in conjunction with a `textvariable`, all you need to do is call `text.set()` and it'll automatically update what the `Label` is displaying. In other words, don't keep creating a new `StringVar` and using `label1.config()` to assign it to the `Label` like you're currently doing.

Comment: in many similar questions I was showing example which uses `after()` to run function which uses `.config` to change text on label and display current time. And `.pack` has nothing to do with this.

Comment: if you want to update `Label` then you should use `after()` rather with `update`, not with `initialize`. You don't have to create `label` again and again.

Comment: Thanks everyone very much! I ended up using a combination of martineau and furas' approaches where I used an update function with `text.set` that is called after an initialization that creates the original label.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use Windows so I can't use module `wmi` but as for me it should be:

I create empty `Label` only once - at start - and I use `after(1000, update)` to run function which gets values from `get_values()` and it updates text on label using `label.config(text=...)`. It doesn't create new `Label`, It doesn't have to check if it need `pack` or `config`. It doesn't need `StringVar` (but frankly I could use it and then I wouldn't need `label.config`)

```
import tkinter as tk
import wmi as w

# --- functions ----

def get_values():
    w1 = w.WMI(namespace="root\OpenHardwareMonitor")
    temperature_infos = w1.Sensor()
    names = ['CPU Package' , 'GPU Core', 'CPU Total']
    values = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

    for sensor in temperature_infos:
        if sensor.SensorType == u'Temperature':
            if sensor.Name == names[0]:
                values[0] = sensor.Value
            elif sensor.Name == names[1]:
                values[1] = sensor.Value
            #else:
            #    pass
        elif sensor.SensorType == u'Load':
            if sensor.Name == names[2]:
                values[2] = sensor.Value
            elif sensor.Name == names[1]:
                values[3] = sensor.Value
            elif sensor.Name == u'GPU Memory':
                values[4] = sensor.Value
            elif sensor.Name == u'Memory':
                values[5] = sensor.Value
            #else:
            #    pass
        elif sensor.SensorType == u'Clock':
            if sensor.Name == u'CPU Core #8':
                values[6] = sensor.Value
            #else:
            #    pass
        elif sensor.SensorType == u'Fan':
            if sensor.Name == u'Fan #5':
                values[7] = sensor.Value
            elif sensor.Name == u'GPU Fan':
                values[8] = sensor.Value
            #else:
            #    pass

    return values

def update():
    values = get_values()
    label.config(text=values[0])
    root.after(1000, update)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.after(1000, update)
root.mainloop()
```

---

Version which emulates changes in `values` and everyone can run it

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ----

def get_values():
    import random
    values = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    values[0] = random.randrange(0, 1000)/10 # float value 0.0 ... 100.0
    return values

def update():
    values = get_values()
    label.config(text=values[0])
    root.after(1000, update)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label = tk.Label(root)
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.after(1000, update)
root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same with `StringVar()` instead of `label.config(text=...)`

```
import tkinter as tk

# --- functions ----

def get_values():
    import random
    values = [0.0 , 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    values[0] = random.randrange(0, 1000)/10
    return values

def update():
    values = get_values()
    label_var.set(values[0])
    root.after(1000, update)

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()

label_var = tk.StringVar()  # to keep value as string
#label_var = tk.IntVar()    # to keep value as integer
#label_var = tk.DoubleVar() # to keep value as float

label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=label_var)
label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

root.after(1000, update)
root.mainloop()
```